# Recommendations Bar: Remove read action (remove from my timeline)

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-recommendations

The Recommendations Bar seems to work well, but there is not an ability to remove the most recent read action from a user's timeline. As all of the actions are handled by the plugin, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the ACTION_ID generated by the Read.

As such, Facebook will not approve my Read Action with the Recommendation Bar because I can't provide a link in the article that says "Remove from Timeline" that deletes the action from a user's timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And just as an update, the "social reading" function of the Recommendation Bar has been removed, probably due to the Read action issues (which were reported as a bug several months ago and marked as fixed at the same time as the feature disappeared). It just replicates the Recommend Box functionality now. –

Answer (score 0):

You read the /me/news.reads API call for the read action with your url as the object and then use that action id for removal.

Comment: Facebook RB TOS requires all actions and calls to be initiated through the Recommendation Bar.

Comment: And just as an update, the "social reading" function of the Recommendation Bar has been removed, probably due to the Read action issues (which were reported as a bug several months ago and marked as fixed at the same time as the feature disappeared).

It just replicates the Recommend Box functionality now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in getting my read action approved. Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't care and will reject your action on the basis that it doesn't provide the user the ability to later delete their actions.

The only way is to build this functionality in manually. The Recommendation Bar Plugin doesn't return the ID for the action after it has been posted to Facebook so you would have to manually query Facebook to get the information back:

```
$activity = $fb->api('/me/' . $action_id );
print_r( $activity );
```

You will then have to display the information correct and let the user delete their information from there.

For my site, I had to create a WordPress plugin to do just that. You can see it in action here:
http://www.xtremeps3.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=facebook-activity/facebook-activity.php

Comment: I'd be interested in learning more about this plugin, but at the moment it doesn't seem to be working? I don't see the read options on the articles on your site and the plugin says no read activity.

Comment: If you use the login button on the right, you will be asked for the "public_actions" permission. This will enable "reading" across the website. Then you should see Activity appear on the page.